# Call a function using a pointer and pass it along in the parameters

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Say that I have a pointer to function `theFunc`. `theFunc` takes along a pointer that points to the address where `theFunc` is stored . Is this possible?

Using it would look like this:

```
funcPtr(funcPtr);
```

That calls the function pointed to by funcPtr, and then passes along the address of the pointer. I do not want to use void pointers because I want to change the function pointed to by `funcPtr`.

Comment: Why would using a void pointer be a problem?

Comment: The C/C++ compiler needs to know what size it is so it can generate the proper offsets.

Comment: @ADBeveridge your last edit actually changed the question. In Stackoverflow you should not change the question after there are some valid answers. Please rollback to your original question and post a new one. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much.

Comment: @ADBeveridge All function pointers have the same size. A void function pointer (as in 'void(*)(void)') shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @wohlstad, my new question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72265253/call-a-function-using-a-pointer-and-pass-the-pointer-that-can-point-to-the-funct)

Comment: @ADBeveridge thanks. I saw you got some answers as well. Hope they help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot simply typedef a function type that accepts itself as a parameter.
I.e. something like this will not work:

```
/* Will cause a compilation error, MyFuncType used a parameter is not yet defined: */
typedef void(*MyFuncType)(MyFuncType);
```

However - you can still use a `void*` to achieve what you want.
The typedef is using `void*`, but inside the function you can cast it to your function pointer type, modify it and call it.

See here:

```
typedef void(*MyFuncType)(void*);

void f(void* pF)
{
    if (pF)
    {
        MyFuncType ff = (MyFuncType)pF;
        /* Change ff here if you need. */
        /* Call it: */
        ff(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    f(f);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update:**
Following the comment from @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica below, I added a **2nd** solution. It does not involve a cast between data and function pointers, but it requires another `typedef` and a cast when calling `f` with itself:

```
typedef void(*FuncType1)(void);
typedef void(*MyFuncType)(FuncType1);

void f(MyFuncType pF)
{
    if (pF)
    {
        /* Change pF here if you need. */
        /* Call it: */
        pF(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    f((MyFuncType)f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that you can safely convert between a function pointer and a data pointer. You probably meant to write something like `typedef void(*MyFuncType)(void(*)(void));` and then adjust `f` analogously.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica but if I change `MyFuncType` like you suggested, and modifies `f` to be: `void f(void(*pF)(void))` I can no longer use `f(f)` to call it with itself. I understand converting a data pointer to function pointer can cause problems, but it's the only way I could make it work (as long as I pass a valid function as an argument). Please demonstrate how this can be done if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Can't you just add an extra cast to make it work?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I updated my answer with a 2nd solution following your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible. C supports incomplete function types in a form of functions declared with no prototypes. For example:

```
int fun();
```

Declares a function that takes an unspecified number of arguments and returns `int`. This allows to define a cascade of function types that approach the desired function type that takes a pointer to itself as a first argument. The desired type reached at infinity but 2-3 levels are enough for practical type safety.

For example, code below compiles without a warning even in pedantic mode.

```
int foo(int(int()));

int main(void) {
  int (*fptr)(int(int())) = foo;
  return fptr(fptr);
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/1s1bGMd9P

Answer (score 1):

> `theFunc` takes along a pointer that points to the address where `theFunc` is stored . Is this possible?

Yes it is possible but it's also 100% pointless. It is similar to addressing a letter to yourself, writing down your postal address in the letter. The you go to place that letter in your own mailbox while you are already present at that physical address stated in the letter. It doesn't make any sense - you already know the address since you are already there, so why write the letter in the first place? Rule #1 in program design: don't do really strange things just because you can.

Any function name in C may decay to a function pointer when used in an expression. Thus:

```
void theFunc (void)
{
  uintptr_t address = (uintptr_t)theFunc;
}
```

There is no need for any parameters.